# dropdown in grid background and text different color

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I'm trying to add a dropdownlist in a telerik mvc grid using column.Bound I can get the dropdownlist to display but initially it displays as a textbox. Apparently if I use an editor template it should work but I get the error value cannot be null?

The aim is to display a dropdownlist in a grid, each item will have a different text color and background. This needs to be populated via model properties.

At the moment I'm using ViewData just to get things working but no joy. Was advised this can be done by Templates.

Any ideas why this isn't working?

```
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@model IEnumerable<TelerikChecklist.Models.ProductViewModel>


@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
.Name("gridDropDown")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
    //columns.ForeignKey(p => p.CategoryID,     (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"], "CategoryID", "CategoryName")
    //  .Title("Category")
    //  .Width(150);

    columns.Bound(p => p.CategoryID).Title("Category Name").ClientTemplate((@Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("dropdown_#=CategoryID#")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
        .DataTextField("CategoryName")
        .DataValueField("CategoryID")
        .ValueTemplate("")
        .ToClientTemplate().ToString()
        )).EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey");

})
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .Pageable()
    .Scrollable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:250px;" })

    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Batch(true)
        .PageSize(20)
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Events(events => events.Error("errorHandler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ProductID);
            model.Field(p => p.ProductID).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.CategoryID).DefaultValue(1);
        })

        .Read(read => read.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Read", "Home"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Update", "Home")).Events(e => e.Change("Category"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Create", "Home"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ForeignKeyColumn_Destroy", "Home"))



    )
```

)

The GridForeignKey.cshtml

```
@model object

@(
Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
    .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])

)
```

Comment: Fixed the null value by updating the GridForeignKey to accept a Ienumerable instead of a select list.

Comment: Got the grid to display using the link below: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22030725/adding-a-dropdown-inside-kendo-grid?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

resolved by creating another template:

```
columns.Bound(p => p.Category.CategoryName).Title("CategoryName").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey2");
```

@using System.Collections;

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
        .Name("NeatProperty")
        .DataTextField("CategoryName")
        .DataValueField("CategoryID")
        .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
        .Template("<div style='background-color:#: data.CategoryColor #'><span class=\"k-state-default\"></span>" + "<span class=\"k-state-default\"><p style='color:#: data.CategoryTextColor #;'>#: data.CategoryName #</p></span></div>")
        .ValueTemplate("<div style='background-color:#: data.CategoryColor #;'><span>#:data.CategoryName#</span></div>")
```

)

Seen this in another post on stackoverflow but lost the link so couldn't post.